# Hamburger Menu - Why doesn't the menu rotate?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, rotation, hamburger-menu

After suffering like a crazy for 4 days I need to get this menu up and running. I need help please.

**When I click on the hamburger menu, it does not rotate (nothing happens).**

The strangest behavior is...

On my local Xampp server, the hamburger menu does not rotate as expected.

**But...In the copepen test block, the hamburger menu rotates.**

The browsers I tested this behavior: **Chrome - Firefox - Brave**

Here is the online version on codepen.

(https://codepen.io/paulodoporto/pen/WNyOEVR)

What am I doing wrong please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mr.Buildbox</title>
</head>
<body>

<header class="sticky-top">
    <!-- header menu on the fron-end page-->
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/buildboxdesafio/assets/images/catdog2.png" alt="" class="responsive-image"></a>
        </div>
    
            <div class="container">

               <!-- Hamburger Menu Tag -->
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-menu">
                <div class="hamburger"></div>
                
                <div class="menu-top-menu-container"><!-- It's not possible remove this Tag -->

                    <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="navigation-class">
                        <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-15"><a href="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/" aria-current="page">IPB Instituto</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/create-page-test/">quem somos</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/faleconosco/">fale conosco</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-28"><a href="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/category/blog/">blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
         
            </div><!-- end <div class="container"> -->    
</header>
```

**{And this is the CSS file}**

```
body {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  font-family: Rubik, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/*img logo header*/
.responsive-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*new css style - 20:28 10.11.2022*/

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #4527a0;
  padding: 0 25px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.logo a {
  display: block;
}

.logo a img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
/* .navigation{} reference */
.menu-top-menu-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
}
/* .menu{} reference */
ul#menu-top-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


ul#menu-top-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(45deg); */
}

ul#menu-top-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  padding: 40px 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

ul#menu-top-menu li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 0px #fff inset, 500px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
  padding: 35px 25px 45px 25px;
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.3s;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  right: 0;
}

.hamburger:before,
.hamburger:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hamburger:before {
  top: -10px;
  width: 20px;
}

.hamburger:after {
  top: 10px;
  width: 25px;
}

.toggle-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger,
.toggle-menu {
  display: none;
}

/* .navigation{} reference */
.container input:checked ~ .hamburger {
  background: transparent;
}

/*The rotation behavior settings, but Onclick nothing happens.*/

.container input:checked ~ .hamburger:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  width: 30px;

}

/*The rotation behavior settings, but Onclick nothing happens.*/

.container input:checked ~ .hamburger:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
  width: 30px;
}

/*The rotation behavior settings, but Onclick nothing happens.*/

.container input:checked ~ .menu-top-menu-container > #menu-top-menu {
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: -20px 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .hamburger,
  .toggle-menu {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: right;
  }
  header {
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  ul#menu-top-menu {
    justify-content: start;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    background: #4527a0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 65px;
  }
  ul#menu-top-menu li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  ul#menu-top-menu li a {
    padding: 22px;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with the **.toggle-menu** class top position. You didn't declare the top position for this. That's why it didn't match the icons. Update the position top like this **top:0;** it will resolve the issue. https://codepen.io/salmanaabir/pen/QWxgOwV

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,400,500,700);

body {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    font-family: Rubik, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/*img logo header*/
.responsive-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/*new css style - 20:28 10.11.2022*/

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: #4527a0;
    padding: 0 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.logo a {
    display: block;
}

.logo a img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

/* .navigation{} reference */
.menu-top-menu-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    float: right;
}

/* .menu{} reference */
ul#menu-top-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


ul#menu-top-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    /* -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(45deg); */
}

ul#menu-top-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    padding: 40px 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

ul#menu-top-menu li a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 0px #fff inset, 500px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
    padding: 35px 25px 45px 25px;
}

.hamburger {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.3s;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    right: 0;
}

.hamburger:before,
.hamburger:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.hamburger:before {
    top: -10px;
    width: 20px;
}

.hamburger:after {
    top: 10px;
    width: 25px;
}

.toggle-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
}

.hamburger,
.toggle-menu {
    display: none;
}

/* .navigation{} reference */
.container input:checked~.hamburger {
    background: transparent;
}

.container input:checked~.hamburger:before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 30px;

}

.container input:checked~.hamburger:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 30px;
}

/* #menyAvPaa:checked ~ #meny {} */

.container input:checked~.menu-top-menu-container>#menu-top-menu {
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: -20px 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {

    .hamburger,
    .toggle-menu {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: right;
    }

    header {
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    ul#menu-top-menu {
        justify-content: start;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0px;
        background: #4527a0;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 65px;
    }

    ul#menu-top-menu li {
        width: 100%;
    }

    ul#menu-top-menu li a {
        padding: 22px;
        font-size: 16px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="sticky-top">
        <!-- header menu on the fron-end page-->
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/wp-content/themes/buildboxdesafio/assets/images/catdog2.png"
                    alt="" class="responsive-image"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-menu">
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
            <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
                <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="navigation-class">
                    <li id="menu-item-15"
                        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-15">
                        <a href="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/" aria-current="page">IPB Instituto</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16">
                        <a href="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/create-page-test/">quem somos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17">
                        <a href="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/faleconosco/">fale conosco</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-28">
                        <a href="https://localhost/mrbuildbox/category/blog/">blog</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end <div class="container"> -->

    </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Salman, thank you for the advide. But I added the property **top:0;** in the tag `.toggle-menu {}` and the behavior is the same. nothing changed in the Browsers.

Comment: I am getting it right both on my codepen and locally.

Comment: As I explained on the Post. On codepen, the Menu is functional, but on my local server and browsers, the Light is not On still.